# Go program is not scaling with more Go routines / cores

Tags: go

I have this data processing code which basically spawns `n` go routines based on the number of cores and takes work as they come in. It involves downloading some files, processing them, finding something using regex and writing values to a csv.

I tried it on a smaller server with 4 vCPUs and it take around 9 minutes but then I tried on a bigger server on Amazon with 192 vCPUS and comparable clock speed the processing time increased to 20 minutes.

Please note that the downloading of the files is not included in the processing time. So it solely involves processing, using regex and writing to a csv. Any help will be appreciated.

Code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/slyrz/warc"
)

var retrier = retry.NewRetrier(10, 100*time.Millisecond, 10*time.Second)

var regex = `regex`
var re = regexp.MustCompile(regex)

func extractData(input string) []string {
    matches := re.FindAllString(input, -1)
    return matches
}

func DownloadFile(url, filename string) error {
    err := retrier.Run(func() error {
        out, err := os.Create(filename)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("error creating file: %s", err)
        }

        defer out.Close()

        fmt.Println("Started downloading:", filename)

        resp, err := http.Get(url)
        if err != nil {
            os.Remove(filename)
            return fmt.Errorf("error fetching file: %s %s", filename, err)
        }

        defer resp.Body.Close()

        _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            os.Remove(filename)
            return fmt.Errorf("error copying file to disk: %s %s", filename, err)
        }

        fmt.Println("Finished downloading:", filename)
        return nil
    })

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

const baseURL = "URL"

func GenerateOutname(input string) string {
    splitted := strings.Split(input, ".")
    return splitted[0]
}

func ProcessFile(filename string) {
    start := time.Now()
    count := 0

    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer f.Close()

    reader, err := warc.NewReader(f)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer reader.Close()

    output := GenerateOutname(filename)
    csvFile, err := os.Create("data/" + output + ".csv")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed creating file: %s", err)
    }

    defer csvFile.Close()

    csvwriter := csv.NewWriter(csvFile)

    for {
        record, err := reader.ReadRecord()
        if err != nil {
            if errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
                break
            }
            fmt.Println("Error reading record", err)
            break
        }

        if record.Header.Get("warc-type") != "response" {
            continue
        }

        uri := record.Header.Get("WARC-Target-URI")
        date := record.Header.Get("WARC-Date")
        data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(record.Content)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error reading from the reader:", err)
            return
        }

        resultString := string(data)
        matches := extractData(resultString)

        for _, data := range matches {
            err := csvwriter.Write([]string{date, data, uri})
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("error writing to csv", err)
            }
            count++
        }
    }

    csvwriter.Flush()

    elapsed := time.Since(start)

    fmt.Printf("%s - Took: %s\n", filename, elapsed)
    fmt.Printf("%s - Data: %d\n", filename, count)
}

func worker(id int, jobs <-chan string, results chan<- int) {
    for job := range jobs {
        remoteFile := job
        url := baseURL + remoteFile

        splitted := strings.Split(remoteFile, "/")
        localFile := splitted[len(splitted)-1]

        fmt.Printf("Started Job: Worker - %d Job - %s\n", id, localFile)

        err := DownloadFile(url, localFile)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Failed to download: %s\n", localFile)
            results <- 1
            continue
        }

        ProcessFile(localFile)
        os.Remove(localFile)

        fmt.Printf("Completed Job: Worker - %d Job - %s\n", id, localFile)
        results <- 1
    }
}

func ReadFiles() []string {
    file, err := os.Open("special.txt")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error opening paths", err)
    }

    defer file.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    records, err := reader.ReadAll()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading paths", err)
    }

    paths := []string{}

    for _, record := range records {
        paths = append(paths, record[0])
    }
    fmt.Println("Total paths:", len(paths))
    return paths
}

func main() {
    files := ReadFiles()
    paths := files

    const workers = 4 // depends on vCPUs
    jobs := make(chan string, len(paths))
    results := make(chan int, len(paths))

    for w := 1; w <= workers; w++ {
        go worker(w, jobs, results)
    }

    for _, path := range paths {
        jobs <- path
    }
    close(jobs)

    for a := 1; a <= len(paths); a++ {
        <-results
    }
}
```

Comment: [Go proverb](https://go-proverbs.github.io) of the day: [Concurrency is not parallelism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=222s)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg any advice on how to make it "parallel"

Comment: Yes. 1. Watch the video. 2. Read to proverbs and watch the videos attached to them. 3. Scale horizontally. If your concurrency setup is sound, that should be easy.

Comment: [Profiling is the way](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime/pprof) to answer these questions.

Comment: You sure your not IO bound?

Comment: @EdH Since, this is only for the processing of files, the I/O task is writing to a CSV file. I would imagine it would scale quite linearly since its just writing to disk. Do you think otherwise?

Comment: @erik258 fair comment. I am not very proficient with profiling so figured ask here for a little help.

Comment: Sure, understandable.  Did you check the link?  Try that out and update the comment if you have issues.

Comment: As to I/O, the EBS IOPS are generally pretty generous, but the default SSD storage option connects storage performance with volume size (where they charge), so look at your EBS volume statistics and it should be fairly obvious if you're bottlenecking there.

Comment: @erik258 can you mention which EBS volume statistics I should look at?

Comment: Even though you have 192vCPU, IO will be your bottleneck, you probably need to implement some kind of counting semaphore, the maximum number should be aligned to IOPS and Throughput. Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPD7TykYy5w&list=PLoILbKo9rG3skRCj37Kn5Zj803hhiuRK6&index=27 for why you have IO bottleneck, and why scaling via many goroutines doesn't work. It's great video for your need. If you can use instance store, it'll be dead simple solution because very high IOPS and Throughput, then find a good number for your counting semaphore and call it a day: )